# How to get TOPN in DAX ignoring duplicate values

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Using filter to get Top 5  by Submitted.

[image]

However it gives me more than 5, due to duplicates.

[image]

How can I tweak or create a measure that would only give me top 5 disregarding duplicates.

I tried to use RANK function but also no success:

```
Rank = RANKX ( ALLSELECTED ( Policy[CodeDescription] ), CALCULATE ( SUM ( Policy[Submitted])  ) )
```

[image]

Comment: It's not duplicates, it's a tie. How do you decide, which ones to discard, if their rank is the same?

Comment: oh, that is right. I would just get the first one in alphabetical order. Which is code4 in this example

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new column and add "Submitted" + RAND() and then rank it based on the new column. Considering you don't have a preference as to which column value gets priority.
Check out the below link for more options:
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/bi/cracking-dax-the-earlier-and-rankx-functions/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by using below measure:

```
Top 5 Code filter = 
VAR toprank = RANKX(ALLSELECTED(Policy[CodeDescription]), CALCULATE(SUM(Policy[Submitted]) + MAX(Policy[ControlNo]) * 0.0000001),,DESC,Dense)
RETURN
toprank
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI6Ji.png)

Below query helped to resolve this issue.
Top 5 Code filter =
VAR toprank = RANKX(ALLSELECTED(gict_riskregisterdetail), CALCULATE(SUM(gict_riskregisterdetail[PICost_RbM_Rnk]) + MAX(gict_riskregisterdetail[Number]) * 0.0000001),,DESC,Dense)
RETURN
toprank

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).